# Telethon, can not get comments from messages telegram

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I am trying to get all the messages/posts from channel and also the comments on them. I successfully got messages from the channel but I could not get the comments. I always get an error. I dont know what it means or even if the method is correct or not. The code is

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from asyncio import run

api_id = 1245242 #Random id
api_hash = "afdsf24242sfdfa524f42sdaedfaAFEfaf" #random hash
chat = 'https://t.me/CryptoAlerts'
# use full phone number including + and country code
phone = "+9256445664" # Random number
name = "username"
async def messages_func(name, api_id, api_hash):
  async with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    print("Extracting messages")
    async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
        async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reply_to=int(message.sender_id)):# This line produces error.
          print(message.text)
       
        #print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
              
run(messages_func(name, api_id, api_hash))
```

The error is.

```
error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

[image: The full image showing Error is]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is most probably caused by the integer casting at `int(message.sender_id)`. Can you check the data type and value of `message.sender_id` ?

Comment: It is an int without using the int function too. <class 'int'>
-1001096895462

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line...:

```py
client.iter_messages(chat, reply_to=int(message.sender_id))
```

..seems needs to be:

```py
client.iter_messages(chat, reply_to=message.id)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html?highlight=iter_messages#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages):

> `reply_to (int, optional)`:
>
> If set to a **message ID**, the messages that reply to this **ID** will be returned. This feature is also known as comments in posts of broadcast
> channels, or viewing threads in groups.
>
> ...

Comment: It worked but some comments are missing

Comment: @farhanjatt, as per missing comments, can you elaborate a bit on what is returned, and how it differs from what you expect?

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty. I am not free I these days. I will comment the details if I get time.